# How to delete lists in Google Drive Docs API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I'm working with the Google Drive Docs API and notice that even when my document is empty it started accumulating a lot of [lists](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/List) on the document object. Each has a list id similar to `kix.lhdvoi8i8aos`.

```js
{
  title: 'XXXX',
  body: {
    content: [
      { endIndex: 1, sectionBreak: [Object] },
      { startIndex: 1, endIndex: 2, paragraph: [Object] }
    ]
  },
  documentStyle: {...},
  namedStyles: {...},
  lists: {
    'kix.eesm2twh6eua': { listProperties: { nestingLevels: [Array] } },
    'kix.1k1bmfaf309l': { listProperties: { nestingLevels: [Array] } },
    'kix.h6tu3k514ze0': { listProperties: { nestingLevels: [Array] } },
    'kix.rfasn08f1d63': { listProperties: { nestingLevels: [Array] } },

    ... cont'd for another 30 lines ...

  },
  revisionId: 'XXXX',
  suggestionsViewMode: 'SUGGESTIONS_INLINE',
  documentId: 'XXXX'
}
```

Unlike the behavior of other components in the google docs API it looks like lists are kept even if all content associated with them is removed. **Is there a way to remove these items?**

I've been looking through the [requests](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request) and can't find the associated command to perform the delete. It's not `DeletePositionedObjectRequest` or `DeleteNamedRangeRequest`. `DeleteParagraphBulletsRequests` asks for a range but there is no range associated with these lists as the document is empty.

Note: I'm using the NodeJS `googleapis` library but as far as I'm aware all api functions are shared between the various language and REST implementations.

Update:
[Git repo](https://github.com/Karasuni/googleapis-docs-lists) with sample code which adds content including a list and then deletes it. After deletion you can see that there is still a lists definition that remains. Each iteration will keep adding lists entries. Is this normal behavior or a bug? Can you remove these list entries?

Update2:
I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1842) on the `google-api-nodejs-client` repository.

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the problem. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jww thats enough code to show the issue IMO i could test it with that alone.

Comment: I don't think there's any relevant code. All I'm asking for is the right API request function that would perform a delete of these lists items.

Comment: @Raven what happends if you post it back with lists removed?

Comment: @DalmTo I wasn't aware there was a way to update the document by sending the whole object. I've only interacted through the Requests API. One detail I did forget to mention is that I'm using the nodejs api library, though from my experience the functions are shared with all language and REST implementations.

Comment: @jww this can be tested right here with the code he has given https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?csw=1#p/docs/v1/docs.documents.batchUpdate   Your right i cant seam to find delete lists.

Comment: @Raven I would like to confirm your situation. So can you provide a sample Google Document? By this, I would like to think of the issue and solution or workaround. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike I've created a git repo with my code which I executed on a pristine document. I observe a list entry remains after deleting all the content related to the entry. You can find the links in the edited Question

Comment: @Raven Thank you for adding the information. I saw your repository. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between your issue of your question and your repository. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Hello! I have created an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142203293) for you.

Comment: @ZektorH if this is intended behavior then my original question here remains: How do I delete these list references?

Comment: @Raven there is no way to delete the unused lists.

Comment: @ZektorH That is a problem - I'm regularly adjusting content and my document might be empty but the object size is creeping up with no way to reduce it.